# Rails / HAML: image_tag inside a link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

How do I write this in HAML?

```
<a class="pull-left" href="#">
  <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64">
</a>
```

I tried this but it failed:

```
=link_to "#", :class => "pull-left
 =image_tag "64x64.gif", :class => "media-object"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the correct way in HAML (note the `do` at the end of `link_to` line):

```
= link_to "#", :class => "pull-left" do
  = image_tag "64x64.gif", :class => "media-object"
```